# No UIView appearing in the interface

Tags: ios

NOTE: Jump to end for answer.

I am new to IOS Programming. How can I add a visible UIView to the following code. So far it just has the nav bar appear, and black space below, no imageView or the square UIView in the code below.

Below is code in my HomeScreenViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *friendsIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"change_user-512"])];
    [friendsIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:friendsIcon];

    UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    [square setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:square];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Below is code in AppDelegate.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.myViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myViewController];
    navBar.title = @"Navigation";

    self.window.rootViewController = navBar;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is also the interface for appDelegate. This is literally the only code in the proj other than the generated lines upon creating the project in xcode. I also deleted the storyboard file along with its info in the plist file (otherwise the app would crash).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomeScreenViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) HomeScreenViewController *myViewController;

@end
```

EDITAgain:
No Need to Read Comments, just read this:
Yes, viewDidLoad does invoke.
The background changes to red if i set background color.
No I am not using storyboard.
Still unanswered.
http://postimg.org/image/h5ayao2q3/

---

FINAL EDIT: Finally! problem solved. It was as simple as setting the background colour for the UIView square. D'oh.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIImageView *friendsIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"change_user-512"])];
    [friendsIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:friendsIcon];

    UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:square];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Thank you very much everyone for your help. I guess my UIImage is borked, but I can figure that out myself.

Comment: given backGround color for view to make sure view is appear.

Comment: Yes I added     [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; to the - (void)viewDidLoad and successfully changed colour to red.

Comment: change_user-512 is your image file?

Comment: @user3492165:  is it ok now ?

Comment: image file is correct, and besides the UIView square should appear right? Neither is appearing, not matter what colour for background.

Comment: Is loadView or viewDidLoad invoked?

Comment: Yes, checked using debugger.

Comment: @user3492165 >> You are making your question too large. If someone now see your question he/she will be mad. So stick to the original question.

Comment: Change the line [square setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; to [square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; and verify it appears on view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First put  breakpoint and verify that ViewDidLoad method is getting called.
2. If not , since you mentioned that you are creating the views programmatically you need to override the `- (void)loadView` method and create the view for the view controller.

   -(void)loadView {

self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];

```
UIImageView *friendsIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"change_user-512"])];
[friendsIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:friendsIcon];

UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
[square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview:square];
```

}

*Changed the line `[square setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];` to `[square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];`*

Comment: Do this first ,self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];

Comment: Well I see not you get the red background of the UIView , try playing with the coordinates of the CGRectMake for the friendsIcon and Square.

Comment: Change this line [square setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; to [square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; and verify it appears on view.

Comment: You fixed it buddy, you're a saviour. I can't believe this simple mistake caused all of this troubleshooting.Props. Make it the answer and I will click the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it:

```
self.myViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] init];
```

TO:

```
self.myViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
```

And Make sure there are some label or some thing in `HomeScreenViewController`. Other part of your code looks fine. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: You mean `self.myViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController" bundle:nil];` right? That crashes and tells me :"reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: ..." as an NSException.

Comment: Do you know why I would receive an exception?

Comment: @user3492165 What type of exception?

Comment: NSException giving message shown in the comment above.

Comment: @user3492165 Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Visit the properties of the .xib files in the file inspector ，the property "Target Membership" pitch on the select box ，then your xib file was linked with your target.

Comment: No, unfortunately not, I am attempting to clean up main post.

Comment: Sure, clean it up. Then try the solution in my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

right click your UIViewController and check view connection is established to the xib or storyboard view.
ViewDidload will not get called unless view loads from storyboard or xib.
loadView method gets called if you are creating UIView programatically

Comment: I do not have a storyboard view. I deleted it because I wanted to make the interface entirely programmatically. Is there something major I am missing for that reason?

Comment: implement your intilaization on - (void)loadView  delegate instead of viewDidLoad . just replace the method name as loadView. have a look in to the viewcontroller lifecycle https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html (Creating a View Programmatically)

Comment: Was there a storyboard and you deleted? Did you also delete the main storyboard setting on .plist?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the app crashed upon launch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using story board or XIB then you need to add the following method

```
 -(void)loadView{
    //load the views 
  }
```

Comment: look at main post, tried and this has thus far made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options to solve this problem:

1) If **you have XIB file** corresponding to the controller:

```
HomeScreenViewController *homeScreenViewController = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController"] bundle:nil];
```

1a. Verify the name of your XIB is correct.

1b. Goto XIB file of `HomeScreenViewController` -> File Owner -> Connection Inspector -> Check the `view` outlet is connected.

2) If you **do it programmatically**, add this to the end of your `loadView` function:

```
self.view = square;
```

so the final code should look like:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    //[super loadView];
     self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];  // <-- look at here, your view has changed its frame now
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIImageView *friendsIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"change_user-512"])];
    [friendsIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:friendsIcon];

    UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    [square setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:square];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: `So self.view = square ` changes the background to black (from red) so yes it does change. None of the subviews are appearing however just as before.

Comment: I haven't noticed that your `self.view`'s frame is zero. You should change it to screen's frame. Look at my updates for option 2, and NO need to set `self.view = square` now.

Comment: added an image in main post. No change unfortunately.

Comment: please clarify two things: 1) you are using XIB or doing it programmatically ? 2) I noticed you have set values in `viewDidLoad` as well as you are using `loadView`. Please make sure your using one of them.